# Items appended to listview are not clickable

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

When I add content to my listview in jQuery Mobile, they don't trigger the click event when clicked. In my example below, 'Cadillac' is not clickable. Am I doing something wrong?

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="p1">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b">
        <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('li').on('click',function(){
    alert('clicked');            
});

$('ul').append('<li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>');
$('ul').listview('refresh');
```

[jsFiddle of the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/88NHA/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change your code to this

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function(){   # <-- That's the trick
    alert('clicked');            
});

$('ul').append('<li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>');
$('ul').listview('refresh');
```

EDIT: In this case `on` function automagically binds `click` to every `li` element in list even when DOM changes. So you can add list items whenever you want. All of them will have click event binding.

Using old `live` jQuery method with almost same functionality is a bad idea cause of it very sloooow performance.

Comment: +1 :-] for answering faster than me ... and maybe you should add some explanation for this "on" syntax (replacing the "live" function)

Comment: I thought `$('li').on('click'..` was the same thing? Such a subtle thing can cause so many problems!

Comment: @Timm, note that he use different syntax - the function will be bind for all current rendered elements and every new one. It is the same as the old "live" function.

Comment: @Joro, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338631/items-appended-to-listview-are-not-clickable/12339229#12339229 any improvisation/suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1):

As at the time javascript was compiled, the li was not present, hense the handler is not applied on it, you need to delegate it to an element which is present at that time..

```
$('ul').on('click','li', function(){
    alert('clicked');            
});

$('ul').append('<li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>');
$('ul').listview('refresh');
```

Or you can use `live()`, or `delegate()`, but `on()` is the best performance-wise

​[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88NHA/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Now is working see [this Edit](http://jsfiddle.net/88NHA/2/)

```
$('ul').append(
    $('<li>').append(
        $('<a>').attr('href','#').append('Cadillac'
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#p1.ul').on('click', 'li' ,function(){
  //Do your stuff
});
```

In simple words: Bind to click event on `#p1.ul` (yes, not `li`) but check if an `li` received the event as well before bubbling to `ul`, only then execute the handler.

I would like you to closely understand the 4 operands/params here, esp #1 & #3

1. Object(s) you are binding to `$('#p1.ul')`.
   jQuery immediately evaluates this expression and binds the function to all the resultant elements, hence **It only binds to elements that were available in the DOM at the time of execution of this statement**.
2. Event you want to bind for `click`
3. Selector for event's source `'li'`
   Note that, the event need not be triggered directly on the `ul` that it binds too, it can be any of its descendant who receives the event, this event then [bubbles](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link3) upwards till it covers all ancestors or is [stopped from propagating](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link9). All the elements may or may not execute an event handler before bubbling it to their parent. Now, once the event [bubbles](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link3) to the `'ul'` element that it was bound to, before executing the event handler a check is made for any of its descendants, that the event was bubbled from, matches the selector `'li'`, only then the event handler is executed and bubbled (unless stopped), else simply bubbled up.
4. The event handler method

So?
When dealing with binding to elements that will be generated at run time, you need to correctly select the #1 & #3. #1 should be such **an element that would survive the lifetime for which you are expecting the event and is an ancestor to the all element(s) that you want to handle the event for, also should be as low in the tree as feasible** (*choosing higher elements will cause performance degradation, as higher the order, more number of descendants, more events will be bubbled to it, which will end up being discarded due to #3 mismatch, not to mention possibility of even triggering on other `li` that were not intended for*). In your case the `#p1.ul` would not be destroyed till a page exists and all `li` would be its descendant, hence is a candidate for #1. If your `ul` is also generated at run-time, you may need to choose an element higher up in the element tree, `body` can be chosen as a last resort. #3 would be the selector of the elements for which you actually want to handle the event for, this choice is generally obvious but easily put for #1 instead of #3.

when you bind directly to `li`'s click event it will bind only to existing `li` elements and not the ones generated after execution of this binding statement.

[More about $.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) & [Example of binding to dynamic elements](http://api.jquery.com/on/#example-7)